# How do I load my api key into rnoaa using R?

Tags: r, api, noaa, ropensci, rnoaa

I am new to r and trying to load my api token to get access to the rnoaa package. I have the API token I just don't know how to access it. Can anyone explain how to load my API key into rnoaa using R? Thanks!

Comment: Try `options(noaakey="yourkeyhere")`.

Comment: @kellis13 Note that you can also pass in your key in the function call as well, e.g., `noaa_stations(stationid='COOP:010008', token="yourtoken")`